# eclipse go to actual implementation

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following class structure. I would like to know how can I jump in eclipse to the actual implementation of th gethod printVar().

If I hover (hold down STRG) over the 2 method calls in main and click open implementation I get both Classes displayed. Is there a way to directly jump to the implementation in class B for this method call w.getWrapperVar().printVar()

```
public class A {

    private String var;

    public A(String a){
        this.var=a;
    }

    public void printVar(){
        System.out.println("class A print: " + this.var);
    }

}

public class B extends A{

    private String var;

    public B(String a){
        super(a);
        this.var=a;
    }

    @Override
    public void printVar(){
        System.out.println("class B print: " + this.var);
    }

}

public class Wrapper {

    private B wrapperVar;
    private A wrapperVar2;

    public Wrapper(String var){
        this.wrapperVar = new B(var);
        this.wrapperVar2 = new A(var);
    }

    // explicit Return Class A
    public A getWrapperVar(){
        return this.wrapperVar;
    }


    public A getWrapperVar2(){
        return this.wrapperVar2;
    }

}

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Wrapper w = new Wrapper("value");

        w.getWrapperVar().printVar();

        w.getWrapperVar2().printVar();

    }

}
```

Comment: `getWrapperVar` returns an `A`, so there is no reason for Eclipse to believe either `A`'s implementation or the one of any of its subclasses is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't know that the implementation class is B, so it can't take you directly to B.

However, you can click on `printVar` and press Ctrl-G to search for all methods that *might* be the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

After selecting a method call you can hit the F3 function key. This action will take you to the definition of the method. This definition may be in an interface. 
When you are in that file you may want to hit Ctrl+T. This will bring up a type hierarchy showing the classes that implement the method you were looking for.
Hope this helps.